# How do I remove the Google Drive icon from the task bar? I do not want to use Google Drive but I still want access to Google search

Tags: google-drive-search

How do I remove the Google Drive icon from the task bar and Google Drive from my computer? I do not want to use Google Drive but I do want to have access to Google search.

Comment: What task bar? Your Windows task bar?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Google Drive app to access the Google search. You can just [uninstall Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375081) and continue to use Google by navigating your web browser to [google.com](https://www.google.com)